# Gradle: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException "Can't read" "Can't write" "Duplicate zip entry"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to integrate a new SDK into my app. The problem is that when compiling I'm receiving this error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\dev\ws\cp-android-v3\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\0.jar] 
(Can't read [C:\Users\name\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.5\9783d89b8eea20a517a4afc5f979bd2882b54c44\httpclient-4.3.5.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] 
(Duplicate zip entry [httpclient-4.3.5.jar:org/apache/http/impl/cookie/IgnoreSpecFactory.class]))
```

I have no idea about what is producing this and how to solve it.

Comment: have you add httpclient-4.3.5.jar file into your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Your new library includes a class (`org/apache/http/impl/cookie/IgnoreSpecFactory.class`) already found in an existing library in your project, but as a different version. The build process does not know which library should take priority, so it is a duplicate.

You may have problems integrating the new library if a common version of this class is not supported by both libraries.

If you look into running the build with "debug" or "show dependencies" enabled, you should be able to find the conflict.

Then look for a way to exclude the class from one of the libraries. There are many ways to exclude classes, including some libraries that have different versions that strip out other library dependencies, or using a keyword like "exclude" for the dependency.

Comment: tryed doing this but not working, same error:

    compile ('com.newsdk:sdk:1.25'){
        exclude group: 'httpclient', module: 'httpclient'
    }